# Eclipse will not run programs or detect errors

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse seems to be pretty screwed on my laptop. Whenever I load a program up from College, it does not detect the errors or anything. Also now when I attempt to run the program, it won't allow it; i'm given the message

> unable to find an ant file to run

Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: clean the project and run again

Comment: Are you create project?

Comment: [Do I look like a Guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Comment: Have a look at this
http://progrepo.blogspot.in/2012/10/eclipse-unable-to-find-ant-file-to-run.html

Answer (score 1):

1-Create a new project in Eclipse

2-After the project is created, look in the package explorer window pane on the left and right click on the src folder.

3-There are two methods for the next step, you could either add a New > Class, and then copy and paste everything from your old java file to the new class (make sure the class name is the same), or the better route would be to Import.

4-After clicking Import, select File System under the general folder. Click Next.

5-Browse for the java folder where your source files are located. Once you click ok, it will add all of the source files to the right pane.

6-Select which files you want to add and click Finish.

7-Now if you look at your Package Explorer window you should see the source files. Now just 
compile them, and the error shouldn't appear and you can run them just like before.

By creating the new project, you're making sure Eclipse knows where your source files are located (in ./src) so that it can compile your code in that location.

Comment: thanks, but i'm now getting the error "Hyperlink error - reason: unable to parse type name from hyperlink." :O